# Why isn't the hover effect on the cards working in my Svelte component? (HTML+CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, svelte

It is my first post here, and I'm seeking help (I am relatively new to programming).

I've tried to make the hover effect work on the cards, but I don't know what is happening. I've tried to put the hover in most of the classes. It was working before some changes to the bootstrap responsive ones (col-md, col-lg, etc).

Here's the code of my Svelte component for you to check out:

```
<h1 class="text-center text-light my-5 animate__animated animate__fadeInDown">
  Projects
</h1>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
      <div
        class="card bg-black text-light border-opacity-25 border-light animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft"
      >
        <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-img-redundant-alt -->
        <img
          class="card-img-top object-fit-fill"
          width="150"
          height="150"
          src="/img/justme.webp"
          alt="Card image"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <strong
            class="card-text d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
            >This Portfolio</strong
          >
          <hr />
          <div
            class="container d-flex justify-content-between align-content-center my-2"
          >
            <img src="/img/svelte.svg" height="40" alt="Svelte" />
            <img src="/img/javascript.svg" height="40" alt="JavaScript" />
            <img src="/img/bootstrap.svg" height="40" alt="Bootstrap" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add more cards here with the same structure -->

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
      <div
        class="card bg-black text-light border-opacity-25 border-light animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft"
      >
        <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-img-redundant-alt -->
        <img
          class="card-img-top object-fit-fill"
          width="150"
          height="150"
          src="/img/countries.webp"
          alt="Card image"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <strong
            class="card-text d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
            >Countries App</strong
          >
          <hr />
          <div
            class="container d-flex justify-content-between align-content-center my-2"
          >
            <img src="/img/angular.svg" height="40" alt="Angular" />
            <img src="/img/typescript.svg" height="40" alt="TypeScript" />
            <img src="/img/bootstrap.svg" height="40" alt="Bootstrap" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
      <a href="">
        <div
          class="card bg-black text-light border-opacity-25 border-light animate__animated animate__fadeInRight"
        >
          <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-img-redundant-alt -->
          <img
            class="card-img-top object-fit-cover"
            width="150"
            height="150"
            src="/img/giphy.webp"
            alt="Card image"
          />
          <div class="card-body">
            <strong
              class="card-text d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
              >GIFs App</strong
            >
            <hr />
            <div
              class="container d-flex justify-content-between align-content-center my-2"
            >
              <img src="/img/angular.svg" height="40" alt="Angular" />
              <img src="/img/typescript.svg" height="40" alt="TypeScript" />
              <img src="/img/bootstrap.svg" height="40" alt="Bootstrap" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4" id="carta">
      <div
        class="card bg-black text-light border-opacity-25 border-light animate__animated animate__fadeInRight"
      >
        <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-img-redundant-alt -->
        <img
          class="card-img-top object-fit-cover"
          width="150"
          height="150"
          src="/img/twitterdb.webp"
          alt="Card image"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <strong
            class="card-text d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
            >Twitter Database</strong
          >
          <hr />
          <div
            class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center my-2"
          >
            <img src="/img/mysql.svg" height="40" alt="MySQL" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add more cards here with the same structure -->
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .card {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 280px;
    min-width: 160;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      135deg,
      rgb(255, 255, 255, 15%),
      rgb(21, 25, 31, 0%)
    );
    transition: transform 0.2s ease, filter 0.2s ease;
  }

  .card:hover {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0px rgb(255, 255, 255, 100%));
    transform: scale(1.05);
    
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .col-sm-6 {
      flex-basis: 50%;
    }
  }
</style>
```

It would be awesome if someone could help and teach me why it is now working.

Thank you and sorry for my English (I'm Spanish btw).

I have tried putting the hover effect in almost all divs, and nothing is working.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use this

```
.card::hover{
   box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #ddd;
}
```

This can help you to get the hover effect

Comment: `hover` uses _one_ colon: `.card:hover`

Comment: No :: add two colons

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover. It's a pseudo-class not a pseudo-element.

Comment: I just solved it. It seems that something was overlapping my cards, so adding a z-index solved it. Thank you for your response anyway and for being my first reply on Stack Overflow :)